# Smoothing the contour line in Python?

Tags: python, contour, matplotlib-basemap

I used the NCEP 2.5 degree*2.5 degree data to plot the 850 mb wind field and heights. But, I didn't know how to smooth the contour line. Scipy.ndimage.zoom didn't work well and some details are missed.

The colorful one is what I want. The another is what I plotted.

[image: 850mb]
[image: my_picture]

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import zoom 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

m=Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=20,urcrnrlat=50,llcrnrlon=90,urcrnrlon=130,resolution ='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()

#read NCEP data
u=Dataset(r'D:\python\TRY\ncep\uwnd.2016.nc','r')
v=Dataset(r'D:\python\TRY\ncep\vwnd.2016.nc','r')
hgt_data=Dataset(r'D:\python\TRY\ncep\hgt.2016.nc','r')

uwnd=u.variables['uwnd'][728][2][:]
vwnd=v.variables['vwnd'][728][2][:]
hgt=hgt_data.variables['hgt'][728][2][:]
lat=u.variables['lat'][:]
lon=u.variables['lon'][:]

#choose selection
index1=np.logical_and(lon>=90,lon<=130);index2=np.logical_and(lat>=20,lat<=50)
lons=lon[index1];lats=lat[index2]
u1=uwnd[index2,:];u2=u1[:,index1]
v1=vwnd[index2,:];v2=v1[:,index1]
hgt1=hgt[index2,:];hgt2=hgt1[:,index1]

#draw wind (vectors)
x,y=np.meshgrid(lons,lats,copy=False)
Q = m.quiver(x,y,u2,v2,scale=250,width=0.003)
qk = plt.quiverkey(Q, 0.85, -0.12, 20, '20 m/s', labelpos='N')

#draw hgt lines
data3 = zoom(hgt2[::2,::2],2,order=3)
levels = np.arange(1420,1560,20)
cs = plt.contour(x,y,data3[:13,:17],levels=levels,colors='k',linewidths=1)
plt.clabel(cs, inline=1, fontsize=8,fmt='%d')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I have met the similar issue. Maybe [this website](https://unidata.github.io/python-gallery/examples/Smoothing_Contours.html) can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved a similar issue using "gaussian_filter".

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
data3 = gaussian_filter(data3, sigma=.6)
```

You can try with different values of sigma.